# Unobtrusive validation not working correctly with Bootstrap Modal Dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

=======================================================================

Update:

The problem was a caused by some custom code written by a previous developer that changed the way forms were being submitted (the code dynamically changed synchronous modal form submissions into Ajax calls without taking into account validation).  Unfortunately this was very hard to detect because of the way it injected itself into certain pages.  I've modified the code and the problem appears to be solved.

=========================================================================

I have a form that's part of a Modal dialog.  The validation *does* run on the various fields (I can see the error messages), and calling `$("#theForm").valid()` returns `false`, but yet the form is still submitted.

However, if I load the content as a simple Partial View instead of as a dynamic Modal Dialog via a button click, everything works fine.  The form is not submitted when there is a validation error.

I've tried removing/adding the Validation when the Dialog is displayed and then re-parsing, but it still doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        alert("Yes, this code does run when the dialog is displayed");
        var form = $("#createUserForm")
            .removeData("validator")
            .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#createUserForm");
    });
</script>
```

Validation is enabled in the web.config file.

What am I missing?

Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult IsRefNumberAvailable(int? refNo, int? userId)
    {
        // Simulate a long call
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult CreateUser(TestModel model)
    {
        return Json(false);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView("_CreateUser");
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set;}

    [Display(Name = "Ref. No")]
    [Remote("IsRefNumberAvailable",
        "Test",
        AdditionalFields = "UserId",
        ErrorMessage = "This Ref number already exists.",
        HttpMethod = "GET"
    )]
    public int? RefNo { get; set; }

    public TestModel() { }

}
```

Index View:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-primary">

    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>
            <div class="row">

            @*Loading the content as a Modal form doesn't work*@
            @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Test", null, new { data_modal = "", id = "btnCreate", @class = "btn btn-small btn-primary" })


            @*But loading it as a Partial View does*@
            @*@Html.Partial("_CreateUser")*@
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Form/Partial View:

```
@model Example.Web.Models.TestModel

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create User</h4>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#createUserForm"));
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateUser", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createUserForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RefNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RefNo, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Ref No" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RefNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">@Html.TextBox("text", null)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Comment: You have double validation js loading. Try to remove "@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")" from both view and partial view and put it to _Layout shared. Maybe this will solve your problem?

Comment: @onedevteam.com Already done so.  That part should not have been included in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This was a wild goose chase.  As indicated in my Update, the previous developer had made a change to the code that was incompatible with BootStrap + jQuery Validation.  I'm going to leave this response here, but this question should be closed.

Comment: That's the first thing I opted for.  However, it appears deleting submissions with answers is not advised (you can have certain privileges revoked) and there's no option to flag to close because a question is no longer relevant.

Comment: Simply flag for moderator attention then.